# NextJS app deployed on Vercel: unable to complete requests from APIs - How to use own API endpoints?

Tags: next.js

I've tried deploying my NextJs app to Vercel and have faced quite some issues. And now I feel stuck again.

I am able to fetch all my data from my DB (MongoDB)successfully, using getStaticProps on the components and fetching right away from the DB. But I am having issues making any API requests to interact with the DB.

Everything works fine when I work locally running `npm run dev` but not when I try to run it on the Vercel server.
My env variables seem to be returning the right addresses to apply the API requests though.

Anytime I try to attempt a request (POST, DELETE, PATCH...) it fails. It is showing me now the error:
[image: error]

I have looked into adjusting my headers to enable CORS following this docs: https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors

I have both created a `next.config.cjs` file as indicated, and also tried to add a middleware to my handler.

I am using `axios` to make the requests. And this is how I make them.

```
axios.defaults.baseURL =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ?
        "http://localhost:3000"
        : `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL}`;

export const createBeer = (beerData: NewBeerData | NewBeerData[]) => axios.post('/api/beers', beerData);

export const getAllBeers = () => axios.get<BeerData[]>('/api/beers');

export const updateBeerData = (beerID: string | ObjectId, beerData: BeerData) => axios.patch(`/api/beers/${beerID}`, { ...beerData });

export const deleteBeer = (beerID: string | ObjectId) => axios.delete(`/api/beers/${beerID}`);
```

For example, on the Edit form, I will call the `updateBeerData` function inside the component after receiving the data from the form.

I have defined my API routes inside my `/api` folder as recommended for a NextJS app. I defined a file to handle all routes as such:

/pages/api/beers/[[...params]].ts

```
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import clientPromise from "../../../../lib/mongodb";
import type { BeerData, NewBeerData } from "../../../types/beers";

// base default url here?

const allowCors = (fn: any) => async (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // another common pattern
    // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version'
    );
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200).end();
        return;
    }
    return await fn(req, res);
};

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const client = await clientPromise;
    // creates and use a db called "test"
    const db = client.db();
    const collection = db.collection("beers");
    // console.log('params', req.params);
    // console.log('req.query', req.query);
    // console.log('req.body', req.body);
    console.log(" ~ file: index.ts:16 ~ handler ~ req.method", req.method);


    switch (req.method) {
        case 'GET':
            try {
                const beers = await collection.find({}).toArray();
                // console.log(" ~ file: index.ts:15 ~ handler ~ beers", beers);
                res.status(200).json(beers);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(" ~ file: index.ts:22 ~ handler ~ get error", error);
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error fetching beers' });
            }
            break;
        case 'POST':
            const newBeers: NewBeerData | NewBeerData[] = req.body;
            try {
                const result = await (Array.isArray(newBeers)
                    ? db.collection('beers').insertMany(newBeers)
                    : db.collection('beers').insertOne(newBeers));

                res
                    .status(201)
                    .json(result);
            } catch (error: any) {
                console.log(" ~ file: index.ts:36 ~ handler ~ post error", error);
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error adding new beers' });
                throw new Error(error).message;

            }
            break;
        case 'PATCH':
        case 'patch':
            // case 'PUT':
            try {
                // const { _id } = req.body;
                const updateData = req.body;
                delete updateData._id;
                const [id] = req.query.params as string[];
                // console.log('req.query.param', req.query.params);
                // console.log(" ~ file: [[...params]].ts:55 ~ handler ~ id", id);
                // console.log(" ~ file: index.ts:49 ~ handler ~ _id", _id);
                await collection.updateOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) }, { $set: { ...req.body } },
                    // {
                    // new: true,
                    // }
                );

                const beer = await collection.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) });
                // console.log(" ~ file: index.ts:53 ~ handler ~ beer", beer);
                res.status(200).json(beer);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(" ~ file: index.ts:49 ~ handler ~ patch error", error);
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error updating beer' });
            }
            break;
        case 'DELETE':
            try {
                const [_id] = req.query.params as string[];
                const beer = await collection.deleteOne({ _id: new ObjectId(_id) });
                // console.log(" ~ file: [[...params]].ts:76 ~ handler ~ beer", beer);
                res.json(beer);
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error deleting product' });
            }
            break;
        default:
            // res.status(405).end();
            res.status(405).json({ message: 'Method not allowed' });
            break;
    }
}

module.exports = allowCors(handler);
```

Before, and after making those 2 CORS (config  file and the middleware) change, I am still getting the same error. They all seem to go to the default case and return a `405 error: Method not allowed`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or missing. How can I use my API endpoints on the production environment, on Vercel?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. A simple fix to this headache.

Basically the use of the VERCEL system environment variables were not the right one to use for my app to work. As they add the deployment id in the URL, and this does not work to fetch your own APIs apparently.

the `PRODUCTION_URL` should be one we set, and not use their default one.

For instance:

```
PRODUCTION_URL = https://<project-name>.vercel.app
```

and don't use `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL`

It fixed my issue, now I can interact with the app in production mode.